# Show status of multiprocessing script without tqdm

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress-bar

I'm writing my first multiprocessing script, which has to be converted to an executable file afterwards. I'd like to have an overview how many files of a list are already processed. But if I use tqdm to do this, my executable file gets extremely large. So I'm looking for a solution to get an impress, how long the task is still working. It doesn't matter if it is a progress bar or just an output in the console like "10 of 120 files done". Has anybody a hint how to do this? I have to pass multiple arguments a, b, c, d, e to the multiprocessing tool, so I have to use "partial" in addition. Then I get one return value for each processed file. This is my code how it works without showing a progress status:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
prod_x=partial(doSomething, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=0, e=e)
totalResult= list((pool.imap_unordered(prod_x, listOfFiles)))
```

The doSomething-Function calculates something and this is done for each file. The parameter totalResult is a list of all returned values

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way to handle this, is probably to use `pool.apply_async` to dispatch your jobs. Then you need to define a callback to execute each time a job is done.

If you want to inform the user about how many jobs that have currently executed, the callback needs some "memory" of the number of executed jobs so far. This can either be a global variable, or a class which I find preferable.

Combining these points, a solution could look something like:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


class ProgressUpdater:
    def __init__(self, num_items):
        self.num_items = num_items
        self.num_processed = 0

    def update(self, data):
        self.num_processed += 1
        print(f"Done processing {self.num_processed} of {self.num_items} inputs")


def func(item):
    time.sleep(item // 10)
    return item // 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    item_list = [3, 5, 7, 32, 6, 21, 12, 1, 7]
    progress_updater = ProgressUpdater(len(item_list))

    with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as pool:
        result_objects = [
            pool.apply_async(func, (item,), callback=progress_updater.update)
            for item in item_list
        ]
        results = [result_object.get() for result_object in result_objects]
    pool.join()

    print(results)
```

Now, to fit your needs, you need to massage it slightly, by using your `partial` functions et c.